# No WLAN adapter on Rapberry Pi 1 A+

Tags: wifi, internet, pi-1, pi-a

### Preliminary Info

- Model 1 A+
- Booting 32-bit raspbian Lite (most recent edition as of March 2021)
- **Goal**: to connect my Pis to the internet for a networking project

### The Problem

I bought two Raspberry Pi 1A+ for projects involving the web, and I have been unsuccessful in connecting to Wifi. Specifically, I can't see any information on `wlan0` after typing `ifconfig`. I've tried various methods involving `wpa_supplicant.conf`, whether it's pre-loading the RPi with a wpa conf file, setting the country, and other suggestions I've seen online.

Upon trying to set the SSID and password in `raspi-config`, I recieve the following two error messages:

> No wireless interface found

> There was an error running option S1 Wireless LAN

I've also tried changing the Localisation settings under advanced options, but to no avail. I get the following error messages:

> No wireless interface found

> There was an error running option L4 WLAN Country

### My Conclusion

So it seems the problem is with the country and the Wifi adapter onboard. I'm not sure if this is a hardware/software problem, and I'm struggling to find any information online.

I also have a RPi 3 and two RPi 4s that run fine with the wpa_supplicant.conf file I usually boot with, it seems to be a RPi 1A+ problem uniquely. Are there setup steps I'm missing for the RPi 1? Am I just out of luck with hardware that is too old? At this point I'm ready to order some RPi 2s and call it a day. Any sort of help in salvaging these RPi 1s would be greatly appreciated. Cheers!

Adrian

Comment: `At this point I'm ready to order some RPi 2s` also don't have wifi ... you could get pi3A+ ... same form factor as the 1A+ but with wifi - or even a zeroW for that matter - the zeroW is about the same as a 1A+ but with wifi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Raspberry Pi 1 Model A+ does not have WiFI, as can be seen on this [product page](https://thepihut.com/products/raspberry-pi-model-a-a-plus) from The PiHut:

Model A+ Specs:

- Dimensions: 65x56x12mm
- Memory: 512MB RAM
- Expansion: Micro SD slot, 1x USB, 40x GPIO
- **Networking: None**

If you are not using the USB port you could utilize a USB WiFi adapter. Alternatively, you could upgrade to a different model of Pi that does include WiFi. A Pi Zero W would likely suffice as it uses the same Chip as your A+ (though it may require an OTG adapter if your application requires USB support). The bigger lesson here is to verify your requirements and make sure your device supports them first.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. I was so sure it was wifi capable. Marking this as solved right away. Thanks so much!